# Почему программа игнорирует условие elif?

Tags: python, if

Есть простенькая задача найти максимальное из трёх чисел. Я её выполнил, но при начальном варианте моего решения игнорировалась одна из инструкций elif. Собственно, вот моя первая попытка решения задачи:

```
if x > y:
    if x > z:
        print(x)
elif y > x:
    if y > z:
        print(y)
elif z > x:
    if z > y:
        print(z)
```

Проблема здесь в том, что программа выполняет первые два условия, но когда я пробую проверить последнее условие, программа ничего не выдаёт и прекращает свою работу.

Answer (score 3):

При невыполнении условия во внутреннем `if`, код во внешний `elif` не попадает.

```
if x > y and x > z:
    print(x)
elif y > x and y > z:
    print(y)
elif z > x and z > y:
    print(z)
```

Comment: можно ещё добавить более практичный пример `max(max(x, y), z)`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon можно, но автору желательно с `if`-ами разобраться